# Left shift bit operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Hello guys,

I am trying to overload the left shift bit operator, `<<`, to do something like:

```
char value[] = "Hello";
value << 2;
```

when doing this I would like to have it printed like: "val", so to delete the last two character; My problem is I can't manage to declare my overloading function properly.

My code is:

```
//the .h file    
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Operators
{
public:
    char *word;
    int number;

    Operators(void);
    Operators(char str[], int num);
    ~Operators(void);
    void Print(void);
    friend char & operator<<(char &stream, int &nr);     
};

#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Operators.h"
#include <iostream>

Operators::Operators(void)
{
    word = "";
    number = 0;
}

Operators::Operators(char *str, int num)
{
    word = str;
    number = num;
}

Operators::~Operators(void)
{
}

void Operators::Print(void)
{
    printf("\nThe String: %s", word);
}

friend char & operator<<(char &stream, int &nr)
{

    return stream;
}

// Operator_Overloading.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Operators.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char value[] = "Hello";
    Operators op(value, 2);


    op.Print();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: This is counter intuitive. Don't do it. Instead, use a different function, with a proper name.

Comment: I agree, this is weird, but you might need a reference to pointer, i.e `char *&stream`

Comment: I would kind of expect left-shifting a string to either add spaces to the right : "Hello  " or shift out the left side: "llo". "Hello" becoming "Hel" seems very right shift-y. Since it's not easy to intuit what the operation would do, it might not be a terrific idea.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot overload any of the operators if they don't involve, at least, one user defined type. Your use case involves a `char[N]` and an `int`, i.e., you can't overload any operators for these arguments.

Comment: The errors I am getting are:
Error 1 error C2803: 'operator <<' must have at least one formal parameter of class type c:\users\raduu\desktop\ms\operator_overloading\operator_overloading\operators.h 
Error 2 error C2255: 'friend' : not allowed outside of a class definition c:\users\raduu\desktop\ms\operator_overloading\operator_overloading\operators.cpp 26
Error 3 error C2803: 'operator <<' must have at least one formal parameter of class type c:\users\raduu\desktop\ms\operator_overloading\operator_overloading\operators.cpp 27

Comment: @user2783292 This error message is a long-winded variation of Dietmar's answer.

Comment: @user2783292: Which part of my answer stating that you cannot overload operators involving only non-class types does not work is unclear to you?

Comment: Ok, I got it, thank you for your clarification. Can you suggest me an example how could I write it?

Comment: @user2783292 Use `std::string` (except that I'd be leery about overloading an operator on a standard type as well).